# Magento-2 get all products having product qty less than 5 only

Tags: magento2, product, collection, inventory

I'm trying to get product collection, only the products which have the qty less than 5 in Magento 2, but I'm failing to load.

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap; 
require DIR . '/../app/bootstrap.php'; 
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER); 
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager(); 
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State'); 
$state->setAreaCode('frontend'); 
$productCollection = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollection->create()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load(); 
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('qty',['lt'=>5])
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$productCollection = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollection->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->load();
 $collection->addAttributeToFilter('qty',['lt'=>5])

Comment: qty filter not working

Comment: is there any way to get collection with qty filters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap; 
require DIR . '/../app/bootstrap.php'; 
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER); 
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager(); 
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State'); 
$state->setAreaCode('frontend'); 
$productCollection = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory'); 
$collection = $productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->joinField(
'qty', 'cataloginventory_stock_item', 'qty', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left'
);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('qty',['lt'=>5]) ->load();
```

Comment: but is there any way to load single product based on qty fiilter

Comment: Welcome, happy to help you!!

you can try this: `$collection->setPageSize(1)->load();`

Comment: @kunj how can we get quantity greater that zero(0) in instock products collections.

Comment: I tried $collection->addAttributeToFilter('qty',['gt'=>0]) ->load(); but showing error The "qty" attribute name is invalid. Reset the name and try again.

Comment: @kunj, this will not load any configurable products, bcz all parent has qty 0. how can we get them with this query

Comment: what if a product has 3 child product and one child has 0 stock quantity and we dont want to show swatches of a product which has 0quantity